# Reference to a derefrenced pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Is the following standards compliant c++ code?

```
int *p;
p = new int;

int &n = *p;
n = 5;
```

Furthermore, am I right in thinking that this code would essentially allocate memory for an int, then give a name, specifically n, to that memory location that could be used like a normal int type variable?

Comment: That is correct. You can print the values with `cout` and check for yourself. :)

Comment: Sure, references and pointers are similar. However, you are obfuscating the original pointer p (being allocated) with the reference n. That is trouble, if the original  is not deallocated.

Comment: I did think of that, and I figured, even if the pointer p got lost, I could deallocate the memory with `delete &n`. I can't really think of any situations where this would actually help though.

Comment: An example where this might be useful is std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> p(new SomeClass); SomeClass &n = *p;   The unique pointer manages the lifetime of the allocated memory while 'n' lets you talk about the object without constantly prefixing it with *.

Comment: That's why * is officially called "indirection" instead of "dereference". Same thing happens when you do "*ptr=1": you are writing into where "ptr" is pointing to, instead of writing to an temporary object created by a dereference operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given code

```
int *p;
p = new int;

int &n = *p;
n = 5;
```

is valid.

I'd write just “yep” as an answer but SO rules – and the sometimes very rule-based users – won't admit such a brief answer.